# Adding Number of Days of Reservation Over Every Month Between Range

Tags: mysql

I'm calculating

1. the number of days a reservation took place over every month (for every month since the first record)
2. A total price based on the total # of days and rate.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `reservations`
   (`id`, `user_id`, `property_id`,     `actual_check_in`,`actual_check_out`)
   VALUES
   (5148, 1,  2, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-10'),
   (5149, 1,  2, '2014-02-03', '2014-02-10'),
   (5151, 1,  2, '2014-02-02', '2014-02-15'),
   (5153, 1,  2, '2014-03-05', '2014-03-10'),
   (5153, 1,  2, '2014-02-20', '2014-03-30'),





   SELECT 
    YEAR(month.d),
    MONTHNAME(month.d),
    r.property_id,
    SUM(
       DATEDIFF(LEAST(actual_check_out, LAST_DAY(month.d)), GREATEST(actual_check_in, month.d))
    ) AS days,
    SUM(days*p.rate),
   MIN(r.actual_check_in) as firstDate,
   MAX(r.actual_check_out) as lastDate
   FROM reservations as r
   LEFT JOIN property as p on r.property_id=p.id
   RIGHT JOIN (
             select
             DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%Y%m%d') as d
             from
             (
             select 
             (firstDate - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(firstDate)-1 DAY) 
             +INTERVAL m MONTH as m1
             from
             (
             select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
             (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
             (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
             (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
             (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
             (select @rownum:=-1) t0
             ) d1
             ) d2 
             where m1<=lastDate
             order by m1
        )      AS month ON
        actual_check_in <= LAST_DAY(month.d)
    AND month.d <= actual_check_out
    GROUP BY user_id, month.d
   ```

Troubles I'm having:

1. getting MySQL to accept a variable for firstDate & lastDate in the joined query
2. I want to sum the monthly number of days together, for reservations by the same user, for the same month. I'm trying to turn the proper parts into a subquery to calculate that but having trouble..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71e34/1

I would like to have the results like (if the property rate is 150/day):

```
DATE     |  USER  |  #Days  |  Total Rate
--------------------------------------
01/2014  |  1     |   9     | 1350
01/2014  |  2     |   0     | 0
02/2014  |  1     |   30    | 4500
02/2014  |  2     |   0     | 0
03/2014  |  1     |   35    | 5250
03/2014  |  2     |   0     | 0
04/2014  |  1     |   0     | 0
04/2014  |  2     |   0     | 0
```

* # days can be more than the # of days in a month because there might be multiple reservations existing during that month

UPDATE---- This almost solved the problem, but I'm having trouble in the second large select statement to actually calculate the prices properly. The query is only taking in to account the first property rate, and not selecting them as per the join statement. Any help?

```
select 
     r.user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%b %Y') as date,
    (SELECT 
        SUM( 
            DATEDIFF(LEAST(actual_check_out, LAST_DAY(m1)), GREATEST(actual_check_in, m1))
            ) AS numdays
       FROM reservations 
        where actual_check_in <= LAST_DAY(m1)
                 AND m1 <= actual_check_out
                 AND user_id=r.user_id
        GROUP BY  m1) as days,

    (SELECT 
        SUM( 
            DATEDIFF(LEAST(r.actual_check_out, LAST_DAY(m1)), GREATEST(r.actual_check_in, m1))
            ) *p.rate  
       FROM reservations  as r
     left join property as p
     on r.property_id=p.id
        where actual_check_in <= LAST_DAY(m1)
                 AND m1 <= actual_check_out
                 AND user_id=r.user_id
        GROUP BY  m1) as price

    from (

    select ('2015-01-01' - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2015-01-01')-1 DAY) +INTERVAL m MONTH as m1 from (
        select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
            (select @rownum:=-1) t0
        ) d1
    ) d2 
      cross join reservations as r
where m1<=CURDATE() group by user_id, m1 order by m1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36035/21

Comment: You won't be able to joing by FirstDate and/or lastDate, because JOIN happens before your MIN() and MAX() gets assigned
By the time you try to JOIN - there is no firstDate or lastDate yet

Comment: Can you post expected result, please

Comment: @cyadvert I made an edit with the results. Thanks!

Comment: dates are weird. Expected results have 2015; but INSERT INTO - 2011 mostly
Are you sure in your expected results table?

Comment: @cyadvert the insert data is just something I had been testing with. There's no real data yet, but I do want this to be able to start at whatever the first date is in the system. So really there should be rows for every month of every year starting at the first reservation.

Comment: I understand, but in order to give you good answer we need to now "real" data. The one, what expected to come in, and what will be the output of that data. Please correct your example.

Comment: @cyadvert ok, hopefully the demo data is more insightful. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: see updated answer. hope it is good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73100/discussion-between-cyadvert-and-ryan).

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure of your request, but the query below may point you to right direction:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(r.actual_check_in, '%m/%Y') AS mnth, r.user_id,
DATEDIFF(MAX(r.actual_check_out),MIN(r.actual_check_in)) AS days,
DATEDIFF(MAX(r.actual_check_out),MIN(r.actual_check_in))*p.rate AS totalRate
FROM reservations r
JOIN property p ON r.property_id=p.id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(r.actual_check_in, '%m/%Y'), r.user_id;
```

This returns data like below:

```
mnth     user_id    days  totalRate  
-------  -------  ------  -----------
01/2014        1       9         1350
02/2014        1      56         8400
03/2014        1       5          750
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36035/36

```
     select 
     r.user_id as userId,
    DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%b %Y') as date,
    (SELECT 
        SUM( 
            DATEDIFF(LEAST(actual_check_out, LAST_DAY(m1)), GREATEST(actual_check_in, m1))
            ) AS numdays
       FROM reservations 
        where actual_check_in <= LAST_DAY(m1)
                 AND m1 <= actual_check_out
                 AND user_id=userId
        GROUP BY  m1) as days,

    (SELECT 

            sum(DATEDIFF(LEAST(r.actual_check_out, LAST_DAY(m1)), GREATEST(r.actual_check_in, m1))*p.rate)

       FROM reservations  as r
      left join property as p
     on r.property_id=p.id
        where r.actual_check_in <= LAST_DAY(m1)
                 AND m1 <= r.actual_check_out
                 AND r.user_id=userId
        GROUP BY  m1) as price

    from (

    select ('2015-01-01' - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2015-01-01')-1 DAY) +INTERVAL m MONTH as m1 from (
        select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
            (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
            (select @rownum:=-1) t0
        ) d1
    ) d2 
      cross join reservations as r
where m1<=CURDATE() group by user_id, m1 order by m1
```